# How can I remove segmenation fault? AA-tree

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is the problem, when filling the tree with elements from 1 to 13, I want to delete element 1 (it will be leaf), the program deletes everything, and then recursively expands, and when it is necessary to update the levels with decrease level, an error is thrown that tree->left = NULL, but the level is not equal to NULL, it is equal to 1, how can this error be corrected?

```
AATree _DeleteData(AATree t, int key)
{
    AATree m;
    if (t == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (key < t->key)                                       // Firstly, Find the node that you want to delete.
    {
        t->left = _DeleteData(t->left, key);
    }
    else if (key > t->key)
    {
        t->right = _DeleteData(t->right, key);
    }
    else {                                                  
        if (t->left == NULL && t->right == NULL)         
        {
            //free(t);
            //return NULL;
            return t->right;                                  
        }
       else if (t->left == NULL)                              
        {
            AATree l;
            l = Successor(t); 
            t->right = _DeleteData(t->right, l->key); 
            t->key = l->key;                                    
        }
        else {
            AATree l;
            l = Predecessor(t);
            t->left = _DeleteData(t->left, l->key); 
            t->key = l->key;                                
        } 
    }
    t = Decrease_level(t);
    t = Skew(t);
    t->right = Skew(t->right);
    if (t->right != NULL)
    {
        t->right->right = Skew(t->right->right);
    }
    t = Split(t);
    t->right = Split(t->right);
    return t;
}

AATree Decrease_level(AATree t) {
    int sb;
    sb = std::min(t->left->level, t->right->level) + 1;
    if (sb < t->level)
    {
            t->level = sb;
     if(sb < t->right->level) {
       t->right->level = sb;
      }
    }
    return t;
}
```

The problem was revealed by the debugger, but I don't understand how to fix it.
According to the program, element 2 should change the level from the second to the first, but it gives an error(tree->left = NULL, function cannot be used "std::min"), but I need its level, that is tree->left->level (level 1)
[How the tree looks after insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqS30.png)

Code: https://repl.it/@RumeOne/Maybe-AA#aatree.cpp

Debug: [Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2geeM.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Added a more detailed description

Comment: an object cannot be `NULL`, only a pointer. Unless you have some odd comparison operator `if (t == NULL)` does not compile. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for adding more explanation. Now please provide a MRE.

Comment: What else can I add? I added function code, picture, problem description

Comment: Did you typedef AATree to be a pointer somewhere? If not, how can stuff like t->level compile? Did you define the right operators to make it compile? If it is a pointer, then watch out for code like `AATree l;` as it doesn't allocate memory for the object

Comment: you should add a [mcve]. Please read the link. A mre has enough code so others can compile and run the code to reproduce the issue. A mre is not necessarily your original code, but a reduced example, that has all that is required to reproduce the issue but not more

Comment: Added a link with all the code

Comment: What happens when you use a debugger?

Comment: Added debugger screen. Instead of checking for tree->left->level(1) for some reason he looks tree->left(NULL)

Comment: I also suggest you change the tag from C to C++ as your linked file's extension is cpp.

Comment: Identifiers starting with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: @Tanveer Badar: I changed the tag from C++ to C, because his code is C, not C++ (alloc, free, raw pointers, typedef struct, etc.) C++ is basically another language. Agree, however that some elements seems leftover from C++ (iostream include and std::min)

Comment: You have posted somewhere (repl.it) 196 lines of code. How difficult would it be to add a `main()` function that shows the sequence of calls of your functions and the parameters? Without that it is not *reproducible* because anybody who *want* to help you can't be sure to get your behavior. That's why it's not a MRE. Further you should strip down the code that only the necessary code is show. That would be *minimal'*. The benefit of creating the MRE is that *you* look at the critical part of your code. Also: it's bad style to post code *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, and especially if you claim "C++", you should NOT program code like yours:

- `free`/`malloc` is old-C, in C++ we use `new`/`delete` in the worse case, but normally we avoid at all cost to use raw pointers, replacing them y smart pointers.
- Use of RAII.
- `NULL` is replace by `nullptr`
- Prefer OOP
- `printf` is replaced by streams.
- Avoid non-english comments (soon or late, this will become a problem for any project). It's already a problem because I can't read your comments.

Obviously, there are exceptions where you might want to get back to raw pointers, `free`/`malloc` and `printf`, but those are rather very exceptional.

This will make your code less error prone and easier to understand.

There is another page of stackexchange (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where you will get lot of good suggestions about your code (it really need it).

Finally, you can use a debugger to run you program line by line until it crashes around aatree.cpp:66

THE ERROR:

The problem is in `Decrease_level`

```
sb = std::min(t->left->level, t->right->level) + 1;
```

This is called from `_DeleteData`, where sometimes, `t->right` or `t->left` is null.

How to get the level of nullptr?

Well, this depends of your algorithm, but probably you can assume the level of the other child?

```
if (nullptr != t->left && nullptr != t->right) sb = std::min...
else if (nullptr != t->left ) sb = t->left->level;
else if (nullptr != t->right ) sb = t->right->level;
else sb = 1;
```

Otherwise, you might use the level of `t` and calculate it child level?

Comment: Yes, I just knew that and wrote what was the error and why, but can I fix it somehow?

Comment: I can tell you why your code does what it does, but I can't imagine what it supposed to do (actually I can, but it will probably not be that code anymore). What does 'level' means exactly?